# add and remove class works with blank link but not with page link

Tags: jquery

I am really noob on jquery but I tried almost more than my best to solved it out by reading old posts created by valuable users of Stackoverflow.
My problem is I try to add class onclick event. Its working only if I set the hyperlink link to blank(#) `<a href="#">test</a>` but if i set to hyperlinks status to `<a href="product.php"` then it removes and adds class for a while and after the current page is open, it automatically removes the active class and set it as previous. :(
My js code..

```
$('ul#menu li a').click(function() {
    $('ul#menu li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: why first removeclass than toggleclass ??

Comment: You need to add `active` class in redirected page manually (static) at specific link or by sending query strings with url and getting them in redirected page (dynamic)

Comment: I want to remove the active class which is set as default to home and remove it when i click on links and add active class the one i click. @ Registered User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is after your example.com/product.php is loaded **active** class does not remain in the respective anchor tag because javascript doesn't carry state old page to a new page when loaded. You can do it in two ways

1. you can disable the page load and stay in same page.

   ```
   $('ul#menu li a').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();//this will stop the current event which is your page load
       $('ul#menu li a.active').removeClass('active');//this will remove the active class from only a tag having active as class
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });
   ```
2. after page load find out which page you are in and set active class for the respective a tag

   ```
   (function($){
        //highlight the current tab
        var l = window.location.pathname,
        str = l.slice(l.lastIndexOf('/')+1,l.length);

       $('ul#menu li a.active').removeClass('active');//remove active from home page link
       $('#menu').find('a[href="'+str+'"]').addClass('active');
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: omg. Thankyou very much..:) The second one works well :). Many Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
var url = window.location.href;
  url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("#menu").find("a[href='" + url + "']").addClass("active");
```

Just include the script to every page and it'll add the `active` class to reflect the current location. No need to toggle anything.

My **guess** why your code doesn't work: You click a link and everything probably works except the link leads to a different page and your jQuery function gets "reloaded" and nothing isn't anymore clicked. If you are trying to implement one page website see for example:

- http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp
- http://cmpolis.github.com/Pagify/#about

Comment: Many many thanks for your valuable comments. I guess my english is little poor. Hope you dont feel like hard to understand my post. I would like to thank whole heartly :)

Answer (score 0):

try using following alone, and remove the `$('ul#menu li a').removeClass('active');`

```
$('ul#menu li a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. and added something like this  
$('ul#menu li a').click(function(){
alert("hell");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
i even added alert("hell"); to check if the code is working.. if alert is inside the function it doesnt popup the message but if the alert is outside the funciton it popup.. what am i missing :( please tell

Comment: <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Firms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="design-detail"><a href="#">Design & Detail</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.php">Products</a></li>
        <li><a a href="#">Dictionary</a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: as shown in code .. your code works only on blank link like <a href="#">test</a> but not with the hyperlink to any page like <a href="product.php"></a>

Answer (score 0):

You should be only using `$(this).toggle('active')`, you don't need the previous statement